# Prove through induction that $\sum_{a=1}^{b}a(b-a)=\frac{b(b-1)(b+6)}{6}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, summation, induction

Given that $\sum_{a=1}^{b}a=\frac{a(a+1)}{6}$ prove through induction that $$\sum_{a=1}^{b}a(b-a)=\frac{b(b-1)(b+6)}{6}$$
Normally I would start by showing that this statement is true for $b=1$ and move on to show that this statement is true for $b=a+1$, but I'm having trouble in this because in my previous induction proves there was only $b$ or only $a$ but now there is $a$ and $b$.

What is the method here?

Comment: The expression you wrote does not correspond to that sum. The value is $\frac{1}{6}(b-1)b(b+1)$

Comment: Was the first expression meant to sum to $\frac{b(b+1)}{6}$? It doesn't make much sense for it to depend on $a$ if you are summing over $a$.

Comment: The "given that" part is wrong even if $a$ is changed to $b$.

Comment: Yes, and even if you assume that the sum is correct, you can check my procedure down below to see that the term he wrote isn't the answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606983/sum-k-1nkk-frac13-fracn6an2bnc-by-induction?rq=1

Comment: See also this question: [How to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)=\binom{n+2}3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1113556). And [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1113556) might be of interest, too.

Comment: BTW you would find some of those questions [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Ba%3D1%7D%5E%7Bb%7Da(b-a)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $a(b-a)=ab-a^2$. Then the sum $S$ becomes:

$$
S=\sum_{a=1}^{b}a(b-a)=\sum_{a=1}^{b}ab-\sum_{a=1}^{b}a^2=b\sum_{a=1}^{b}a-\sum_{a=1}^{b}a^2
$$

By hypothesis $\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{b}a=\frac{b(b+1)}{6}$. By induction you can prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{b}a^2 = \frac{1}{6}(2b+1)b(b+1)$. Finally:

$$
b\left(\frac{b(b+1)}{6}\right)-\frac{1}{6}(2b+1)b(b+1) = \frac{-1}{6}b(b+1)^2
$$

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{b}a^2  = \frac 16 (b)(b+1)(2b+1)$

Comment: Completely true! Sorry I messed up while computing the sum. Still the answer is not what OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

For an induction, of the title formula, get rid of the summation index $a$, by rewriting
$$
1\cdot(b-1)+2(b-2)+3(b-3)+\cdots (b-1)\cdot 1=f(b)
$$
with the correct poylnomial $f(b)$. Start with $b=1$. What do you obtain for $b\mapsto b+1$?

Answer (score 1):

As it is written your proposition is not true.

The left side is clearly an integer, while for $b=2$ the right side produces a fraction.  There is no factor divisible by $3$ in the numerator.

However, when you have it sorted out what proposition you are actually trying to prove...

Take care of the base case.

Assume:

$\sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b} a(b-a) = f(b)$

Show.

$\sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b+1} a(b+1-a) = f(b+1)\\
\sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b+1} a(b+1-a) = \sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b} a(b+1-a)$

Because the last term in the series on the $LHS = 0.$

$\sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b} a(b+1-a)\\
\sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b} (a(b-a) + a)\\
f(b) + \sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b} a$

By the inductive hypothesis.

You have probably already proven that $\sum_\limits{a = 1}^{b} a = \frac 12 b(b+1)$

And then you will need to do just a little algebra to show that:

$f(b) + \frac 12 b(b+1) = f(b+1)$